# How to tackle a problem where dataset has high variance involved

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, inference, repeated-measures

Suppose, If I have twenty confidence scores for twenty different images as defined below object classified as cats, and its average is 58.9%. For first image, the confidence score is 25.9% and for the second image it's 93.3% and for the third image it's 92.8% and so on. So there is a high variance involved in these data.

```
cat [[0.2596674 ]]
cat [[0.9336238 ]]
cat [[0.9280105 ]]
cat [[0.40792587]]
cat [[0.29937932]]
cat [[0.7761701]]
```

If I have to decide between two different systems for classification, system-I and system-II, based on the average score, I retrieved 58.9% for system-II (Neural Network model), I am deciding to go for system-I (Neural Network model) for classification, and provide my input image to it, but I am deciding based on average which is wrong since high variance is involved, maybe for the first-time system-I will provide 76.5% and on next time it may provide a poor performance 23.1%.

How to tackle a problem like this help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't follow your explanation. What is the key difference between system I and system II?

Comment: not sure what your confidence accuracy scores are, but in general, you can use something like a paired t-test or mcnemar test for these things

Comment: Thanks @gunes, system I and system II are two different DNN models

Comment: Thanks@rep_ho, confidence threshold (score) is the probability softmax max layer provides. its not the accuracy of test data during training of model

Comment: It sounds like you’ve discovered stochastic decoding by accident, and you’re trying to compute expected accuracy on the cat prediction task. Instead, I encourage you to employ proper [tag:scoring-rules].

Comment: Thanks @AryaMcCarthy for your suggestion.

Comment: I wish folks were clearer on problems before they shut-down (potentially) decent questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: still under construction

**interpretation**:
I think you might be asking about the bias-variance tradeoff.  How do you minimize the miss-rate?

**tool:**
I like to use 'R' to simulate answers to questions like this.

**slight rephrase:**
Given two classification schemes, one that has a higher mean accuracy, but higher variance, and another that has lower mean accuracy but lower variance, how do I choose the scheme that is more likely to work well?

**Engaging it:**
There is hand-waving to be had, but I think the normal distribution is not a terrible 2-parameter starting point for an exploration like this.

There are 3 variables that we are going to want to "sweep" and not 4.  I could imagine sweeping two means and two variances if this were not a bounded domain, but because it is accuracy and not the real line, I think we have to look at it differently.  I think we can pin one mean and variance, and consider the other in reference to that.  So I like the reference having 50/50 and sweeping the other in terms of that.  I think we could do a set of fixed values for the variance  instead of "every value" and look at a smaller comparison set.

**Note: still under construction**